# HiTouch_PressGestureDetector error, limitied touch pointer

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, smooth-scrolling

I'm working on flutter project. I'm using singleChildScrollView and listView for scrolling.
But when I want to scroll in any screen in app I face to this error:

```
  W/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector(20161): Touch pointer move a lot. The moving distance of X 
  is:11.0, limit is:60The moving distance of Y is:69.0, limit is:60
```

This prevent user to have smooth scrolling on app, even on released version.

I don't know exactly what is the reason of this error.
As additional information, I'm using flutter_unity,syncfusion_flutter_charts packages in my app.

Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: any update? I am experiencing the same problem!

Comment: Same here did you find solutions @KaitoKuroba?

Comment: @KaitoKuroba Not yet. I think it is because of resources management and increase performance of app

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

These weird messages are randomly shown when we are using **Huawei devices**. I think we can ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50794#issuecomment-586918190) for this in Flutter. An [open issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50808) was being tracked publicly by Flutter team to address this warning messages:

> After [#45743](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/45743), we
> stopped filtering log output (by the string `flutter` both because it
> broke benchmark tasks and because it obscured when the app crashed.
> The downside is that the logs are much noisier. This should be
> configurable by a flag.
>
> For more context, see:
> [#50628](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50628)